# php prepared statements || Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

The code below is returning this error (Line numbers are in brackets[])

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' location, type, capacity, length, qty, serial, cert, lastinsp, inspby, datein, ' at line 1' in D:\Websites\riggingregister\pdo.php:90 Stack trace: #0 D:\Websites\riggingregister\pdo.php(90): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Websites\riggingregister\pdo.php on line 90
```

I've edited the entry manually in PHPMyAdmin and the suggested 'PHP Code' came out as:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `riggingregister`.`register` SET `register` = \'100\',
`location` = \'testing\', `type` = \'Chains - 4 leg\', `capacity` = \'10mm\',
`length` = \'testing\', `qty` = \'testing\', `serial` = \'testing\', 
`cert` = \'testing\', `lastinsp` = \'testing\', `inspby` = \'testing\',
`datein` = \'testing\', `dateout` = \'testing\', 
`status` = \'HOLD\', `notes` = \'EDITED!\' WHERE `register`.`id` = 1;";
```

But I'm not sure how I can translate that into my prepared statement.

I've been reading tutorials, manuals and every possible question that SO offered me and can't see where I'm going wrong. Would love for someone to point me in the right direction.

Cheers

```
echo "the <b>CONFIRM CHANGES</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";

    $query = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE register SET register, location, type, capacity, length, qty, serial, cert, lastinsp, inspby, datein, dateout, status, notes VALUES ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? WHERE id = $id');
    $data = array($register, $location, $type, $capacity, $length, $qty, $serial, $cert, $lastinsp, $inspby, $datein, $dateout, $status, $notes);
    $query->execute($data);

    echo "Data has been written to the database!<br /><br />";
```

Comment: It is very hard to read the code. You can simply paste it into your question, select it and press CTRL-K. This should code format it nicely for you.

Comment: What is the update query?

Comment: despite adding the line numbers for ease of reading, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @ZachFlem your update query does not look normal?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong format for `UPDATE` Your query is still open to injection by passing $id directly. Add $id to end of $data array.

TRY

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE register SET register =?, location =?,... WHERE id = ?');
$data = array($register, $location, $type, $capacity, $length, $qty, $serial, $cert, $lastinsp, $inspby, $datein, $dateout, $status, $notes,$id)
$query->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
echo "the <b>CONFIRM CHANGES</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";

$data = array(
    'register' => $register,
    'location' => $location,
    'type' => $type,
    'capacity' => $capacity,
    'length' => $length,
    'qty' => $qty,
    'serial' => $serial,
    'cert' => $cert,
    'lastinsp' => $lastinsp,
    'inspby' => $inspby,
    'datein' => $datein,
    'dateout' => $dateout,
    'status' => $status,
    'notes' => $notes
);

$fieldDetails = NULL;

foreach($data as $key=> $value) {
    $fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
}

$fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ',');

$dbh = $this->prepare("UPDATE register SET $fieldDetails WHERE id = :id");

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $dbh->bindValue(":$key", $value);
}

$dbh->bindValue(":id", $id);

if($dbh->execute()) {

     echo "Data has been written to the database!<br /><br />";
}
```